# Mobile application: cookies ignored in PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, apache2

My scenario is as follows: my mobile application sends a request to an external website for authorization to receive an authorization code, which is send to a redirect URI to be exchanged for an 'access token'. I want to store this token in firebase real-time database, but with the unique user id of the user making that request through my app. Reason, there could be multiple users making that request to the website and of course I need to separate them, including secure storage of the token. Without the uuid, everything is working and the token is saved to firebase.

I've now started to update my code. OAuth 2.0 is used, however, state management is not set on the 3rd party wesbite, so I can't just pass on the encoded uuid as the server only returns the authorization code. So I wrote a script (storeUuid.php), that receives the encoded uuid, decodes it, saves it in a timed cookie, so that other scripts on the same domain (auth.example.com) can access the cookie and use it. There is a second script on the server (redirect.php), that is triggered by the authorization request to the 3rd party website, receives the authorization code and is supposed to exchange it for the access token. However, prior to that, it shall access the cookie and extract the uuid. However, it always throws the {error:UUID not found in the cookie}.

```
<?php
// storeUuid.php
session_start();
// Function to return JSON response
function jsonResponse($data) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

// Function to log errors
function logError($message) {
    error_log("Error: $message");
}

session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 3600,
    'path' => '/', 
    'domain' => 'auth.example.com', 
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' => 'None' 
  ]);

// Function to store UUID in session and cookie
function storeUUID($encodedUUID) {
    $decodedUUID = base64_decode($encodedUUID);
    
    if ($decodedUUID) {
        $_SESSION['userUid'] = $decodedUUID;
        setcookie("decodedUUID", $decodedUUID, time()+3600, "/", "auth.example.com"); 
        jsonResponse(["success" => "UUID stored in session and cookie.", "decodedUUID" => htmlspecialchars($decodedUUID), "sessionId" => session_id(), "cookie" => ($_COOKIE)]);
    } else {
        logError("No UUID provided or decoding failed.");
        jsonResponse(["error" => "No UUID provided or decoding failed.", "sessionId" => session_id()]);
    }
}

// Check if the request method is POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $encodedUUID = isset($data['encodedUserUid']) ? $data['encodedUserUid'] : null;

    if ($encodedUUID) {
        storeUUID($encodedUUID);
    } else {
        logError("No encoded UUID provided in POST request.");
        jsonResponse(["error" => "No encoded UUID provided in POST request.", "sessionId" => session_id()]);
    }
} else {
    logError("Invalid request method.");
    jsonResponse(["error" => "Invalid request method.", "sessionId" => session_id()]);
}
?>
```

```
<?php
// redirect.php
session_start();
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException;

$serviceAccountPath = __DIR__.'/1234ABCD.json';
$databaseUrl = 'https://fundraiser-application-example.com';

function jsonResponse($data) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

// Function to log errors
function logError($message) {
    error_log("Error: $message");
}

// Retrieve the decoded UUID from the cookie
if (isset($_COOKIE['decodedUUID'])) {
    $decodedUUID = $_COOKIE['decodedUUID'];
} else {
    logError("UUID not found in the cookie");
    jsonResponse(["error" => "UUID not found in the cookie"]);
    exit;
}

print_r($_COOKIE); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['userUid'])) {
    logError("User UID not found in session");
    jsonResponse(["error" => "User UID not found in session"]);
    exit;
}

try {
    $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccountPath)
        ->withDatabaseUri($databaseUrl)
        ->createDatabase();
} catch (FirebaseException $e) {
    logError("Firebase Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    jsonResponse(["error" => "Firebase Error: " . $e->getMessage()]);
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    logError("General Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    jsonResponse(["error" => "General Error: " . $e->getMessage()]);
    exit;
}

$clientID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
$clientSecret = 'MY_SECRET_Key';
$tokenURL = 'https://auth.3rdparty.com/oauth/token';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];
    $postData = http_build_query([
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $clientID,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'code' => $authorizationCode,
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://auth.example.com/redirect'
    ]);

    $context = stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => $postData
        ]
    ]);

    $response = file_get_contents($tokenURL, false, $context);

    if ($response === FALSE) {
        logError("Error in token request");
        jsonResponse(["error" => "Error in token request"]);
        exit;
    }

    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($responseData['access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $responseData['access_token'];
        $userUid = $_SESSION['userUid'];

        $firebase->getReference('users/' . $userUid . '/example/access_token/')->set($accessToken);
        jsonResponse(["success" => "Access Token stored successfully for user", "userUid" => htmlspecialchars($userUid)]);
        
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    } else {
        logError("Access token not found in response or user UID not available in session");
        jsonResponse(["error" => "Access token not found in response or user UID not available in session", "response" => $responseData]);
    }
} else {
    logError("Authorization code not found");
    jsonResponse(["error" => "Authorization code not found"]);
}
?>
```

Those are the two files. As said, the response logs I get from storeUuid.php show everything working as far as I can tell:

```
LOG  Initiating OAuth process...
 LOG  Encoded user UID: ABCD1234
 LOG  Response from storeUuid.php: Array
(
    [decodedUUID] => BFM6OIHuCBe56s08cgcnmiEotff1
    [PHPSESSID] => lgh2gphfbbolcimv0abkkmrere
)
{"success":"UUID stored in session and cookie.","decodedUUID":"5678DCBA","sessionId":"my_session_id","cookie":{"decodedUUID":"5678DCBA","PHPSESSID":"my_session_id"}}
 LOG  Authorization URL: https://auth.3rdparty.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=(MY_CLIENT_ID)&redirect_uri=https://auth.example.com/redirect&scope=read
 LOG  OAuth URL opened successfully.
```

But the browser on the device I'm testing the app is throwing that error it can not find the UUID in the cookie or session.

I added print_r($_COOKIE); in redirect.php to see what the cookie content is, but nothing is shown.

Any recommendations would be very helpful!

Comment: Not sure why you are using a separate, "stand-alone" cookie for this - when you already have a PHP session in use? For your session ID cookie, you have set SameSite to None, but for your separate cookie, it is not being set, so the default will apply. Depending on the browser, that can make a difference here (the redirect back from the OAuth login site, to your redirect URI, is where SameSite applies.)

Comment: Even if I set it to Lax, the result stays the same.

Comment: Then you'll have to do some more debugging on the actual mobile device, I suppose, to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: The issue is that its not your client thats accessing `redirect.php` but the 3rd parties client and I guess they dont send cookies with the request so there is no cookie with useruid. Session wont work either because its basically a cookie, too. Are you using firebase auth? Or what provider in specific and are the tokens JWTs?

Comment: As you're currently making request to the external website for authorization and passing a unique identifier (UUID) as a parameter in the request, the following must be met: 1. Store UUID on the server and 2. Exchange Authorization Code for Access Token. Please check the feedback that will send shortly.

Comment: // storeUuid.php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $uuid = $_POST['uuid']; 

    // Store the UUID in the session
    $_SESSION['uuid'] = $uuid;

    // Show the relevant message
    echo json_encode(['message' => 'UUID stored successfully']);
} 

// redirect.php
// Use the authorization callback and exchanges the code for an access token.

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    // Retrieve the stored UUID from the session
    $uuid = $_SESSION['uuid'];

    if ($uuid) {
        // Proceed with exchanging the authorization code for an

Comment: @CodeSpirit Yes, I'm using firebase auth. The goal is to save the access token with the uuid of the loggedin user in the firebase realtime database.

Comment: @LawrenceEBosumbe I've tried that. The problem is with the two different method (POST and GET) once coming from mobile app (POST) and once from the 3rd party server the sessions (id) are different. So if I call $uuid = $_SESSION['uuid']; in redirect.php its 'null' as $uuid is saved in another session, that was triggered by the different request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using a customized session handler.

```
class CustomSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface {
    private $redis;

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
        // Initialize the Redis connection
        $this->redis = new Redis();
        $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
        return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        // Close the Redis connection
        $this->redis->close();
        return true;
    }

    public function write($id, $data) {
        $this->setSessionData($id, $data);
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id) {
        $data = $this->redis->hGet("session:$id", "data");
        return $data === false ? '' : $data;
    }    

    public function destroy($id) {
        // Attempt to delete the session data from Redis
        $result = $this->redis->del("session:$id");
        
        if ($result === false) {
            // Log the error or handle it accordingly
            error_log("Failed to delete session data for ID: $id");
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }     

    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
        // Redis automatically handles expiration, so no need for manual garbage collection
        return 0;
    }

    public function setSessionData($id, $data) {
        // Set session data in your custom way
        $this->redis->hSet("session:$id", "data", $data);
        $this->redis->expire("session:$id", 600); // data expires after 10 minutes
    }

    public function getSessionData($id) {
        // Retrieve session data from Redis based on the session ID
        return $this->redis->hGet("session:$id", "data");
    }
}

// Register the custom session handler and start session
$handler = new CustomSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

Comment: Thats only a workaround because I think you have an issue in your general auth flow.
I was irritated because of your usage of "authcode" because thats a reserved word in oauth 2 but I think you just mean the access token.
When doing firebase auth or any 3rd party oauth you normally 1. Authenticate on the client and receive the access token 2. Send the access token to the server to server 
3. The access token is now authenticatting the request
You can then decode it on server (using firebase admin sdk in your case) and then get the users firebase id / email for further usage.